# Detect Java NumberFormat inaccuracy

Tags: java, number-formatting

I want to parse an integer accurately, one that has been potentially formatted according to the current locale. If I didn't parse the integer accurately, I want to know it. So I use:

```
String string = "1111122222333334444455555";
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(locale);
numberFormat.setParseIntegerOnly();
Number number = numberFormat.parse(string);
```

Obviously `"1111122222333334444455555"` represents a big number, bigger than a `Long` can handle. So `NumberFormat` gives me... a `Double`??

I guess I would have expected to receive a `BigInteger` rather than a `Double`, especially since I asked for an integer-specific number formatter. But never mind that; the bigger problem is that the double value I get back is `1.1111222223333344E24`! This is not equal to `1111122222333334444455555`!!

If `NumberFormat` gives me a parsed value that does *not* equal that stored in the input string, how do I detect that?

Put another way: "How can I know if the `Double` value I get back from `NumberFormat` is exactly equivalent to the integral value represented in the original string?"

Comment: If you use the simple `Long.parseLong()`, you'll get an overflow exception.

Comment: Why not simply construct a BigInteger with the input string instead of trying to parse it?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I need to support values that have been possibly formatted in the current local (e.g. "1,234" in the USA). I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @ConorSherman In most cases I'm working with `Long`. I don't want to be forced into using `BigInteger` unless the number requires it. Plus the `BigInteger` constructor doesn't pay attention to locale (see updated question).

Comment: You cold still consider it. If you need to validate that it conforms to the locale rules, that's one thing, but you can still parse it easily by filtering out everything but digits.

Comment: Or why not just check that the return value is a `Long`? If it isn't that's the sign of overflow, isn't it?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik "...you can still parse it easily by filtering out everything but digits". No, that is not correct---I can't just ignore the non-digits. Ignoring the comma in string value `"1,234"` in the `en_US` locale would yield the integer `1234`, sure, but in the `fr_FR` locale I would need to detect that `"1,234"` is not a valid integer at all (it's the floating-point value `1.234`).

Comment: That's what I'm getting at -- first a locale-sensitive validation (NumberFormat could do it), then `Long.parseLong`. But now I don't see what would be wrong with testing the type of the return value.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think the title question was not the best. I've changed it to indicate that I want to detect, not necessarily an overflow, but when the returned value is not an accurate representation of the value in the input string.

Comment: A `Double` is as good as never an accurate representation of the input string, and a `Long` is always of perfect fidelity.

Comment: @MarkTopolnik "A 'Double' is as good as never an accurate representation of the input string..." That's a very interesting assertion. Of course we all know that there are many fractional values a floating-point number cannot represent. Does your assertion hold for integral values? You seem to be saying that if I cast a `long` to a `double` and then back to a `long`, most of the time I won't wind up with the same value---which would really surprise me. If you were talking about fractional values, I would agree---but that's not relevant here.

Comment: "1.1111222223333344E24 This is not equal to 1111122222333334444455555" what do you mean by that ? Do you want them to be equal as a string or as a number ? example: "2+3" and "5" are not equal as string but as a number they are same. only representation is different.

Comment: @MohammadAdil Please double-check your scientific notation conversion---the first value is missing a bunch of `5`s.

Comment: @GarretWilson i copied from your question :)

Comment: @MohammadAdil Yes, I know---the two values are different, which is the point of the question.

Comment: This is by now probably clear, but still---"most of the time I won't wind up with the same value": that's actually true, and the further away from zero, the more accurate the statement. Around the extremes of `long`'s range the density is about one in two thousand (one `long` in two thousand can be represented by rounding some `double` value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) for `parse()` state that it will return a Long if possible, otherwise it will return a Double.  So just check that the return value is a Long.

"Returns a Long if possible (e.g., within the range [Long.MIN_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE] and with no decimals), otherwise a Double."

> "How can I know if the Double value I get back from NumberFormat is exactly equivalent to the integral value represented in the original string?"

If it returns a Double, then it is **not** exactly equivalent to your integral value because a Double cannot accurately represent values at that magnitude.  Concrete example:

```
  Number a = numberFormat.parse("-9223372036854775809"); // Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1
  Number b = numberFormat.parse("-9223372036854775810"); // Integer.MIN_VALUE - 2
  System.out.println((a.equals(b))); // prints "true"
  Number c = numberFormat.parse("-9223372036854776800");
  System.out.println((a.equals(c))); // prints "true"
```

Comment: My title wasn't quite clear enough. What I really want to detect is whether the returned value accurately reflects the value in the string. So if a `double` is returned that contains the value `Long.MIN_VALUE + 1`, that's fine if that's what was in the string. But how do I know if the value returned is what was really in the string?

Comment: @GarretWilson Take this into account: a `long` covers all the possible signed integers that can be accurately represented with 64 bits. When `long` overflows, it will already be many, many integers past the last point where consecutive `double` values still manage to cover consecutive integers (that is, are able to accurately represent those integers after rounding).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That is an interesting observation, but I'm not sure how it answers the question, "How can I know if the `double` value I get back from `NumberFormat` is exactly equivalent to the integral value represented in the original string?" I'm not talking solely about overflow; sorry about the confusion---I've edited the title.

Comment: Exactly.  Long.MIN_VALUE - 1 = "-9223372036854775809".  There is no way to accurately represent that as either a Long or a Double.  `NumberFormat.parse()` will return a Double, which lets you know that it isn't accurately representing the integral number.  For Long.MIN_VALUE + 1, it will return a Long, letting you know that the number was OK as an integral value.

Comment: @Enwired Oh, so you're saying that `double` cannot represent any integral values beyond the range of `long`?

Comment: @GarretWilson You can simply be sure that if it's a `Double`, it isn't exactly equivalent to any integral value. I think 0 is the only such integer (this may be wrong, but it's a side point anyway). The only hope is that it *rounds* to your desired integer, and even that test will fail for all but very scarce few integers in the range outside `Long`'s.

Comment: @GarretWilson  Double can ~represent~ `1e+45`, for example, but since it can't tell the difference between consecutive integers at the size, I would say that it can't ~accurately~ represent an integral value of that magnitude.

Comment: I've checked, the mantissa is 52 bits long, so basically you can hit one in every 2^(64-52) integers near Long.MAX_VALUE. That's one in over four thousand.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for the discussion, I've included some more info in the answer based in part on your comments.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it is the closest given, perhaps the closest possible. This answer actually answers the question, "How can I know if the `Double` value I get back from `NumberFormat` is _probably not_ equivalent to the integral value represented in the original string?" Thanks also to input by @MarkoTopolnik, it seems that while `double` can represent `long` values accurately, outside that range it represents only a few integral values accurately. It turns out the question of "overflow" wasn't that different after all; the `NumberFormat` API return value is a bit odd, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

For you question -

```
If NumberFormat gives me a parsed value that does not equal that stored in the input string, how do I detect that?
```

You can use

```
    if(number.toString().equals(string))
      //Parsed correctly
   else
     //Invalid parse
```

Comment: good idea, but that is not locale-independent. `number.toString()` is locale-independent, but `numberFormat.parse()` is locale-sensitive, and he wants a procedure that will work in a locale-sensitive way.

Comment: I think this is not what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution but worth notice.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "1111122222333334444455555";
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(locale);
        numberFormat.setParseIntegerOnly(true);
        Number number = numberFormat.parse(string);
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(number.toString());
        System.out.println(b.toBigInteger());

    }
```

Output of this code is : `1111122222333334400000000`

As you can see this is not equal to the number in the actual string , so their might be an overflow occoured.

Comment: I fail to see how this code answers the question. Can create a method that inputs a `String` and returns a `Number`, and if the resulting number is not identical to the value in the original string, it throws an exception? I fail to see how the code you gave does that.

Comment: What i am doing in that code is - converting 1.1111222223333344E24(parsed) this into a bigInteger so that we can compare it with original number that is in string form.

Comment: Yes, but you'll find that it won't work with locale-specific input representations such as "1,234" or "1.234".

Comment: In reference to Enwired's answer he said "if it returns a Double, then it is not exactly equivalent to your integral value because a Double cannot accurately represent values at that magnitude" - i showed the same thing with an example...

Comment: No, you showed how _one_ `double` value didn't equal an input integral value in string form---but we already knew that, because that was the question! Moreover, you also claimed that you could _detect_ whether the output `double` value was exactly equal to the integral value in the input string, and your code does not do this! If you claim it does, rewrite the method to use the signature `public Number parseNumber(String string, Locale locale) throws IllegalStateException` where it throws the exception if the parsed number value would not equal the integral value in the string.